# Transforming a list of two-dimensional coordinates into a flat list of relative changes

Tags: python, python-2.x, coordinate-system, generator

I have a little function that parse a nested list of coordinates into a flat list of compressed coordinates. By compressed coordinates, I mean that only the delta (distance) between each coordinates are stored in the list and the float coordinates are transformed in integer.

```
input = [[-8081441,5685214], [-8081446,5685216], [-8081442,5685219], [-8081440,5685211], [-8081441,5685214]]
output = [-8081441, 5685214, 5, -2, -4, -3, -2, 8, 1, -3]

def parseCoords(coords):
    #keep the first x,y coordinates
    parsed = [int(coords[0][0]), int(coords[0][1])]
    for i in xrange(1, len(coords)):
        parsed.extend([int(coords[i-1][0]) - int(coords[i][0]), int(coords[i-1][1]) - int(coords[i][1])])
    return parsed

parsedCoords = parseCoords(input)
```

As the input list is really big, is there a way to improve the function, maybe by using generators or list comprehension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for i in xrange(1, len(coords))` is a red flag, since it is preferred in python to iterate directly over the elements rather than the indices. If you trully need the indices, you can still use `enumerate`.

Here it would look like

```
for i, coord in enumerate(coords[1:]):
    previous = coords[i]
    parsed.extend([int(previous[0] - coord[0]), int(previous[1] - coord[1])])
```

which seems worse as it

1. creates a copy of `coords` when slicing it;
2. still uses an index to retrieve the previous element.

Instead, it seems better to convert the list into an iterator an manually handle the current/previous coordinates. Something like:

```
def parse_coordinates(coords):
    iterator = iter(coords)
    previous_x, previous_y = iterator.next()
    parsed = [int(previous_x), int(previous_y)]
    for current_x, current_y in iterator:
        parsed.append(int(previous_x - current_x))
        parsed.append(int(previous_y - current_y))
        previous_x, previous_y = current_x, current_y
    return parsed
```

You can note the use of `append` instead of `extend` that will avoid building a temporary list. `append` try to be smart when resizing the underlying array so that two consecutive `append`s should not have more performance hit than `extend`.

But all in all, using `append` or `extend` in a for loop is often better written using a list-comprehension or a generator. You can easily turn this function into a generator by turning these `append` into `yield`s:

```
def parse_coordinates(coords):
    iterator = iter(coords)
    previous_x, previous_y = iterator.next()
    yield int(previous_x)
    yield int(previous_y)
    for current_x, current_y in iterator:
        yield int(previous_x - current_x)
        yield int(previous_y - current_y)
        previous_x, previous_y = current_x, current_y
```

There is an other advantage to this approach: if the `coords` parameter is empty, your approach using `coords[0]` and the first one building a list using `iterator.next()` will crash raising either an `IndexError` or a `StopIteration`.

This generator can easily be fed to the `list` constructor or a `for` loop and won't crash; producing either an empty list or not entering the loop.

---

Lastly, you could drop manually managing the previous/current thing by using [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) which is the key feature of the `pairwise` recipe:

```
from itertools import tee, izip


def parse_coordinates(coords):
    prev, cur = tee(coords)
    x, y = cur.next()
    yield int(x)
    yield int(y)
    for (previous_x, previous_y), (current_x, current_y) in izip(prev, cur):
        yield int(previous_x - current_x)
        yield int(previous_y - current_y)
```

Answer (score 3):

**1**.Python functions are using underscore as naming separator

So your function `parseCoords` should be named as `parse_coordinates`, please read [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

**2**.Your current code can be simplified to

```
from itertools import chain
input = [[-8081441, 5685214], [-8081446,5685216], [-8081442,5685219], [-8081440,5685211], [-8081441,5685214]]
output = [-8081441, 5685214, 5, -2, -4, -3, -2, 8, 1, -3]


def get_diff(pair):
    a, b = pair
    return int(a[0] - b[0]), int(a[1] - b[1])


def parse_coordinates(coords):
    # keep the first x,y coordinates
    parsed = chain.from_iterable(map(get_diff, zip(chain([[0, 0]], coords), 
                                                   coords)))
    return list(parsed)
```

**3**. If you really thing you code list is going to be huge, you might convert this function into a generator so you will use only O(1) memory instead of O(n). To do this with code above using
**Using python 2**

```
from itertools import chain, imap, izip
input = [[-8081441, 5685214], [-8081446,5685216], [-8081442,5685219], [-8081440,5685211], [-8081441,5685214]]
output = [-8081441, 5685214, 5, -2, -4, -3, -2, 8, 1, -3]


def get_diff(pair):
    a, b = pair
    return int(a[0] - b[0]), int(a[1] - b[1])


def parse_coordinates(coords):
    # keep the first x,y coordinates
    parsed = chain.from_iterable(imap(get_diff, izip(chain([[0, 0]], coords),
                                                     coords)))
    for item in parsed:
        yield item
```

**Using python 3**

```
from itertools import chain
input = [[-8081441, 5685214], [-8081446,5685216], [-8081442,5685219], [-8081440,5685211], [-8081441,5685214]]
output = [-8081441, 5685214, 5, -2, -4, -3, -2, 8, 1, -3]


def get_diff(pair):
    a, b = pair
    return int(a[0] - b[0]), int(a[1] - b[1])


def parse_coordinates(coords):
    # keep the first x,y coordinates
    parsed = chain.from_iterable(map(get_diff, zip(chain([[0, 0]], coords),
                                                   coords)))
    yield from parsed
```